# PHP Dificuldade de entender erro

Tags: php

O código é responsável por atualizar a senha do usuário caso ele esqueça e gerar uma nova hash para recuperar a senha, faço isso para que o link de recuperação de senha funcione somente uma vez.
O comportamento atual é o seguinte: A primeira alteração de senha funciona normalmente, porém, se abrir o mesmo link utilizado na primeira vez, que já teve seu token sobrescrito, o código da a mensagem de alteração bem sucedida, porém o update não funciona. Preciso que quando o update falhar, caia dentro do if e imprima a mensagem de erro ao usuário.

```
<?php
require_once("../../requires/connect.php");   // Conexao com o banco de dados
require_once("../../requires/bcrypt.php");    // Classe Responsavel pela criptografia
require_once("../../requires/functions.php"); // Funcoes

// criptografa a senha digitada
$hash_pass = Bcrypt::hash($_POST['senha']);
$update = "UPDATE usuario SET senha = '$hash_pass' WHERE recuperar_senha = '{$_POST['recuperar_senha']}'";
if ($mysqli->query($update) === FALSE) { // Caso falhe, informa o usuario e pede para tentar novamente
    Functions::alertaRedirect("Falha ao realizar a troca, tente novamente.", "../definir_senha.php??zeqe0eZoda28goklt3W0={$_POST['recuperar_senha']}");
}
// Gera novo hash para recuperar senha
$novo_pass_rec = Bcrypt::generateRandomHash();
// Salva o novo hash de recuperacao de senha no bd
$update = "UPDATE usuario SET recuperar_senha = '$novo_pass_rec' WHERE recuperar_senha = '{$_POST['recuperar_senha']}'";
if ($mysqli->query($update) === FALSE) { // Caso falhe, informa o usuario e pede para tentar novamente
    Functions::alertaRedirect("Falha ao realizar a troca, tente novamente.", "../definir_senha.php??zeqe0eZoda28goklt3W0={$_POST['recuperar_senha']}");
}
Functions::alertaRedirect("Troca Realizada com sucesso!", "../../../index.html"); // Informa o usuario que a troca foi bem sucedida.
?>
```

Comment: A questão é: se o token foi sobrescrito o seu UPDATE alterará um total de zero registros. Ou seja, o UPDATE é executado com sucesso. Por que não verifica se a senha foi alterada verificando se `mysqli->affected_rows` é igual a 1? Se for 0 o token não existe mais - se for maior que 1 algo muito preocupante aconteceu.

Comment: Certo, vou fazer o teste e mais tarde informo se funcionou, obrigado!

Comment: Eu fiz mas não entendi/consegui fazer funcionar, acredito que estou fazendo errado:         

$update = "UPDATE usuario SET senha = '$hash_pass' WHERE recuperar_senha = '{$_POST['recuperar_senha']}'";
if ($mysqli->affected_rows == 0) { mensagem de erro
}

Comment: Você ainda precisa executar a `query`, mas não é o resultado dela que deve verificar e sim da `affected_rows`.

Comment: Deu certo, obrigado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Com a ajuda do Anderson, consegui resolver o problema. O código final fica da seguinte maneira:

```
$update = "UPDATE usuario SET senha = '$hash_pass' WHERE recuperar_senha = '{$_POST['recuperar_senha']}'";
$mysqli->query($update);
if (mysqli_affected_rows($mysqli) == 0) { // Caso falhe, informa o usuario e pede para tentar novamente
    Functions::alertaRedirect("Token expirado, solicite a troca de senha novamente!", "../definir_senha.php??zeqe0eZoda28goklt3W0={$_POST['recuperar_senha']}");
}
```

O mesmo raciocínio se aplica ao segundo IF. Agora o código verifica quantas linhas foram alteradas, caso nem uma tenha sido, é impressa a mensagem de erro corretamente.